# Parsing JSON dictionary with arrays with JSON Parsing does not result in NSDictionary or NSArray?

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to parse a JSON dictionary in the form of:

```
{ Data: "[{"GID_ID":"350b4bab-5032-4784-434e-a45100af805c","SYS_NAME":"Aareshh, A 0808880001 (Inforeca Tech)"},{"GID_ID":"aba267b4-317a-46dc-434e-a4440079d424","SYS_NAME":"Bala, Jyothi 04022220000 (MacWee Tech)"},{"GID_ID":"631083b4-45f3-4b23-434e-a4580067401f","SYS_NAME":"Jack, Sparrow 0808880001 (Inforeca Tech)"},{"GID_ID":"f6725028-ce34-46ca-434e-a4510097cb58","SYS_NAME":"Jerry, Tim "},{"GID_ID":"ffc8cfe7-683d-49c9-434e-a44100e4838f","SYS_NAME":"kumar, pratap 040669933 App Dev (Infodat pvt tech)"},{"GID_ID":"61fc723f-f530-4216-434e-a44a00eb887a","SYS_NAME":"Manthena, Ramu "},{"GID_ID":"9c8114a2-a207-453f-434e-a466008f75e3","SYS_NAME":"Pawan, krishna 8972346767 "},{"GID_ID":"e8e1831b-99b2-4ef6-434e-a42e00f2a4f1","SYS_NAME":"super 2, super 1 "},{"GID_ID":"cb98ec8b-5bfe-4833-434e-a42e00f389cf","SYS_NAME":"super 2, super 1 414-449-6000 Bus Dev Mgr (Eaton Corporation )"},{"GID_ID":"8bf09fc6-84a6-407b-434e-a43a00c88585","SYS_NAME":"Thoutam Contac - Gmail, Ravi G mail 2098903655 (Tesco - Company)"},{"GID_ID":"097e7639-9e81-4d3e-434e-a44a00eb7837","SYS_NAME":"Velga, Swetha 04022220000 (MacWee Tech)"}]",Status: "Success"}
```

I am having difficulties getting to the proper data within this structure.Total Response storing the Dictionary(myDict). My goal is I want to get the GID_ID and SYS_NAME in data.

I need help creating the object. Currently, when I create the NSDictionary using JSON, I only obtain one dictionary, with a single NSCFString:

```
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:myKeyresponsedata encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    _responseData= nil;
    myKeyDict = [responseString JSONValue];
    NSLog(@"Response String %@",myKeyDict);
```

I want to get the GID_ID, SYS_NAME.

Answer (score 1):

Data you receive isn't well formed :

```
{"Data":"[{
```

As I read, your array is within quotation marks which results in a string indeed.

Answer (score 0):

use this website : http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

to check the content of your JSON.

You can also use this : http://jsonlint.com/ to check if its legit.

In your case only the json is legit, but the first link will tell you that you have a format issue, because what's inside your Data is a string, not sub-layers of your json.

I'd remove the " !

Answer (score 0):

If that is the JSON that you receive, then someone is sending you rubbish. You can't parse it, because it isn't JSON.

There must be quotes around "data". And there must be no quotes around [{ ... }]. Get the people responsible for generating the JSON to fix it.